# How to ignore specific errors in an Ansible task

Tags: ansible

If have an Ansible task, that can fails sometimes, due to some error during the creation of an user account. Especially if the user account is already in use and the user is logged in. If the task fails with a specific error message, like "user account in use" the play must continue. There is no need to fail then, but only on predefined error messages. The task looks like this.

```
- name: modify user
  user:
    state: "{{ user.state | default('present') }}"
    name: "{{ user.name }}"
    home: "{{ user_base_path }}/{{ user.name }}"
    createhome: true
```

Since it's not a shell command, I cannot simply register a var and check the output of .rc. Also I don't get stderr or stdout, when i register a var and print it in debug mode. That was my first approach on check for the error message. I am running out of ideas, how to filter for a specific error and passing the task, but failing on everything else. ignore_errors: yes is not a good solution, because the task should fail in some cases.

Comment: [Register](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_variables.html#registering-variables) can be used without the shell module.

Comment: This is correct, but I don't get the rc as a return value and for some reason I also don't see stdout or stderr for the user module. This makes it difficult to filter for a specific error.

Answer (score 2):

As per ansible doc we get `stdout` and `stderr` as return fields.

I would suggest to use flag `ignore_errors: yes` and catch the return as per this example

```yaml
---
- hosts: localhost
  vars:
    user:
      name: yash
    user_base_path: /tmp
  tasks:

    - name: modify user
      user:
        state: "{{ user.state | default('present') }}"
        name: "{{ user.name }}"
        home: "{{ user_base_path }}/{{ user.name }}"
        createhome: true
      register: user_status
      ignore_errors: yes

    - name: stdout_test
      debug:
        msg:  "{{ user_status.err }}"

    - name: Fail on not valid
      fail:
        msg: failed
      when: '"user account in use" not in user_status.err'
```

Output:

```bash
PLAY [localhost] *************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [Gathering Facts] *******************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [modify user] ***********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "err": "<main> attribute status: eDSPermissionError\n<dscl_cmd> DS Error: -14120 (eDSPermissionError)\n", "msg": "Cannot create user \"yash\".", "out": "", "rc": 40}
...ignoring

TASK [stdout_test] ***********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "<main> attribute status: eDSPermissionError\n<dscl_cmd> DS Error: -14120 (eDSPermissionError)\n"
}

TASK [Fail on not valid] *****************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "failed"}

PLAY RECAP *******************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=3    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=1    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=1
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [when](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_conditionals.html), save the return value by the [register](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_variables.html#registering-variables) and [set_fact](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.9/modules/set_fact_module.html)  and then bet what will happen according to that value.